# How to ensure that root is the only UID 0 account?

Tags: linux, bash

I created two users `test` and `test2` with UID of 0 and 1001. When I run this script the first condition is working which is `$i != "root"` so the output is that it prints both `test` and `test2` but not `root`. However my second condition does not work.

```
#!/bin/bash

result="$(awk-F: '($3 == 0) { print $1 }' /etc/passwd)"
uid=$(stat --format=\%u /etc/passwd)

for i in $result
do 
    if [ $i != "root" ] && [[ "$uid" -eq 0 ]]; then
    grep ^i /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1,3
fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it with awk from the start?

```sh
#!/bin/bash

users=( $(awk -F: '$3 == 0 && $1 != "root" {print $1}' /etc/passwd) )

if [[ ${#users[@]} != 0 ]]
then
    echo "non-root users with uid = 0: ${users[*]}"
fi
```

Or by returning a non-zero exit code with awk and saving the output at the same time:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if users=($(awk -F: '$3==0 && $1!="root"{print $1;rc=1}END{exit !rc}' /etc/passwd))
then
    echo "non-root users with uid = 0: ${users[*]}"
fi
```

Comment: I intended to echo or show the "not root users and uid = 0" after meeting a condition if it is possible.

Comment: Updated the answer to save the non-root users with uid=0 in a bash array

Comment: It is not showing any outputs

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to negate the result in the second example

Comment: I removed the rc and the script works

Comment: It is okay. Thank you for the help!

Comment: That's not correct to remove `rc`; it'll always print `non-root users with uid = 0:` even when there's no users

Comment: Therefore the first option will not work too if that is the case?

Comment: The first option checks the **number** of non-root users with uid=0; the second option checks the **return code** of the awk command. Both work